# What is the safest way to reassemble pickled Python objects in a stream?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, pickle

I'm currently sending pickled Python (3.8) objects via sockets between two running programs. I have a buffer of bytes I want to reconstruct into their corresponding objects on the receiving end.

To my understanding, the `socket.recv` method is not guaranteed to catch all bytes sent, and it's up to the caller to call `socket.recv` again to pick up the rest of the data. So, at any given time, my buffer could contain partial packets.

Additionally, due to my use of threading, I could receive multiple messages before I check the buffer.

Here's my question:

**Given that I'm receiving a byte stream of arbitrary length, which may contain fewer or more than one pickle object, what is the best way to reassemble them?** Is there a character I can use as a terminator that is guaranteed to not conflict with `pickle`?

Comment: There is no character, or sequence of characters, that can be guaranteed not to be present in a `pickle`.  The usual way of sending multiple chunks of unknown size over a stream protocol is to precede each chunk with its length;  call `.recv()` until you've received the entire length indication, then keep calling `.recv()` until you've received that number of bytes.  The lengths themselves could either be of a fixed size, or use some terminating character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a character I can use as a terminator that is guaranteed to not conflict with pickle?

Unfortunately there isn't. Pickle packs data in binary form, therefore any sequence of bytes can appear inside a pickled object.

> what is the best way to reassemble them?

The most common (and probably also the easiest) thing to do when dealing with this kind of problem is to send a fixed-size header that indicates the size of the data that is going to be received.

You can use [`struct.pack()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.pack) to create an 8-byte header containing the binary representation (as an 8-byte network-endian unsigned integer) of the size of the pickled object, and send it before the actual data. On the receiving end, you'll first receive the 8-byte header, then you'll decode it to know the size of the data that was sent, and finally receive exactly that number of bytes.

Here's a (simplified) example:

- Sender:

  ```
  class Example:
      pass

  data = pickle.dumps(Example())
  size = len(data)
  header = struct.pack("!Q", size)

  # open socket...

  sock.sendall(header)
  sock.sendall(data)
  ```
- Receiver:

  ```
  class Example:
      pass

  def receive_exactly(sock, n):
      data = b''

      while n > 0:
          chunk = sock.recv(n)
          n -= len(chunk)
          data += chunk

      return data

  # open socket...

  header = receive_exactly(sock, 8)
  size = struct.unpack("!Q", header)[0]
  data = receive_exactly(sock, size)
  e = pickle.loads(data)
  ```

Note that the two above snippets only serve as simple examples, you should do the proper error checking and handling when using `sendall()` and `recv()`.